# To what extend does shared roots imply divisibility of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, roots

I am looking for knowledge and intuition about the relation between shared roots  and divisbility.
More specifically, I am interested in statements in the following spirit:

> Let $p$ and $q$ be two polynomial functions $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$.
>   If all roots of $p$ are also roots of $q$, then $p$ divides $q$ (there is a third polynomial $r$ so that $q=pr$).

This statement is not true as stated.
Consider, for example $p(x)=1+|x|^2$ and $q(x)=1$ or these two multiplied by the same polynomial.
My intuition seems to suggest that the only obstruction to this statement is bad behavior of $p$ (the only example I could think of is variants of having $1+|x|^2$ as a factor), whereas $q$ can be anything.

Is there a theorem or theory that explain to what extent the statement above is true?
Does the statement hold for some "sufficiently nice" polynomials $p$?
Does it hold in general modulo some kind of an error term in $q=pr$?
I am specifically interested in it over the reals; the answer may well be different over an algebraically closed field.
If there is no general theory or the general answer is a mess or even unknown, that would be useful to know as well.

In the case $n=1$ this is simpler.
Assume that $p$ can be factored to first order terms.
Then if a root of $p$ is a root of $q$ with at least equal multiplicity, then $p$ indeed divides $q$.
In particular, the statement is true if $p$ has degree one.
If $p$ has a second order irreducible factor (of which $1+x^2$ is a good example), then the statement fails.
I am looking for this kind of understanding for $n\geq2$.

Comment: You should not use $|x|^2$ in a polynomial - $x^2$ will do. To illustrate the dangers, $x^2$ is a polynomial over the complex numbers, but $|x|^2$ is not. There are plenty of polynomials having no roots in $\mathbb R$, and this turns out not to be the right context for the question you are asking - in the sense that other contexts give better answers along the lines of your suggestion. I should work over one dimension first, and understand that - your question essentially opens up the realm of algebraic geometry as stated.

Comment: @MarkBennet Here $x\in\mathbb R^n$, so I would consider $x^2$ a somewhat misleading abbreviation of $\sum_ix_i^2$. I know that the squared absolute value is not a complex polynomial, but I am emphatically working over the reals. I should have included something about the case $n=1$ my answer; I'll edit.

Comment: Apologies, I was thinking of simple examples in one dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Think first about how this works with the factorisation of integers. $m=12$ and $n=18$ both have prime factors $2$ and $3$, but with different multiplicities. What we can say is that both are divisible by $2\times 3$ and that $12^2=18\times 8$ while $18^2=12\times 27$. We have that each divides a power of the other.

You can do the same with polynomials eg $p(x)=(x-2)^2(x-3)$ and $q(x)=(x-2)(x-3)^2$

So as well as taking care about what a root is, and working in an appropriate context to count all the roots, you also need to take care of multiplicities, even in very simple examples.